# Why isn't rvalue copy constructor used for assignment from temporary?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class test {
public:
    test(int y) {
        printf(" test(int y)\n");
    }
    test() {
        printf(" test()\n");
    }
    test(test&&c) noexcept {
        printf(" test(test&&c) noexcept\n");
    }
     test(const test&z) {
        printf(" test(const test&z)\n");
    }
    test& operator=( test&&e) {
        printf(" test& operator=( test&&e)\n");
        return *this;
    }
};
int main()
{
    test o ;
    o = 4;
    return 0;
}
The Output :
 " test() "
 " test(int y) "
 " test& operator=( test&&e ) "
```

I thought that this line in the code o = 4 is creating an rvalue of object of the class ( test ) and passing it to the overloaded operator ( operator = )

But when i changed

```
test& operator=( test&&e )
```

into

```
test& operator=( test e )
```

and run the code again :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class test {
public:
    test(int y) {
        printf(" test(int y)\n");
    }
    test() {
        printf(" test()\n");
    }
    test(test&& c) noexcept {
        printf(" test(test&&c) noexcept\n");
    }
    test(const test& z) {
        printf(" test(const test&z)\n");
    }
    test& operator=(test e) {
        printf(" test& operator=( test e)\n");
        return *this;
    }
};
int main()
{
    test o;
    o = 4;
    return 0;
}
   The Output :
     " test() "
     " test(int y) "
     " test& operator=( test e ) "
```

While I expected this Output after the change :

```
     " test() "
     " test(int y) "
     " test(test&&c) noexcept "
     " test& operator=( test e ) "
```

Because when i changed

```
test& operator=( test&&e )
```

into

```
test& operator=( test e )
```

the overloaded operator ( operator = ) now takes an object of the class test as parameter ( pass by value ) and the value that is passed to it is an rvalue so I expected that the constructor `test(test&&c) noexcept` will be called

So why the constructor

```
test(test&&c) noexcept
```

is not called?

Explanation why I have this expectation:

because when you write this code and run it :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class test {
public:
    test(int y) {
        printf(" test(int y)\n");
    }
    test() {
        printf(" test()\n");
    }
    test(test&& c) noexcept {
        printf(" test(test&&c) noexcept\n");
    }
    test(const test& z) {
        printf(" test(const test&z)\n");
    }
    test& operator=(test e) {
        printf(" test& operator=( test e)\n");
        return *this;
    }
};
int main()
{
    test o;
    test x;
    o = move(x); // this function ( move () ) returns an rvalue of its argument 
    return 0;
}


The Output :
     " test() "
     " test() "
     " test(test&&c) noexcept "
     " test& operator=( test e ) "
```

**edit :**
this code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class test {
public:
    test(int y) {
        printf(" test(int y)\n");
    }
    test() {
        printf(" test()\n");
    }
    test(test&& c) noexcept {
        printf(" test(test&&c) noexcept\n");
    }
    test(const test& z) {
        printf(" test(const test&z)\n");
    }
    test& operator=(test e) {
        printf(" test& operator=( test e)\n");
        return *this;
    }
};
int main()
{
    test o;
    test x;
    o = x;
    return 0;
}
   

The Output :
     " test() "
     " test() "
     " test(const test&z) "
     " test& operator=( test e ) "
```

Comment: **Bold** text is only to be used to add emphasis. It is not for formatting every single line of your post. You do **NOT** need to bold everything in your post.

Comment: In your second example, `o=4` creates a temporary object, and you have an assignment operator that accepts an object of the class.  Perfect match.  Why would there be another constructor involve?

Comment: I explained my reason @Tim Roberts

Comment: The key is, it doesn't NEED to create another object.  It already created an object (using the `int` constructor), and you have an assignment operator that accepts an object.

Comment: if lvalue is passed to an assignment operator that accepts an object like this code 
`test o ;
  test r;
  o = r;`
the Output of this code is 
    " test() "
     " test() "
     " test(const test &z)  "
     " test& operator=( test e ) "
@Tim Roberts

Comment: I edited the code in the question @Tim Roberts

Comment: I think Tim's first comment explained what happened. Please elaborate on your question. `4` itself would be constructed into a rvalue object by int constructor `test(int)`. Compiler doesn't need another rvalue constructor `test(test&&)` since your assignment operator accepts an rvalue which comes from `4`. `test(test&&)` might take place when you assign a lvalue to another lvalue to convert an lvalue to rvalue implicitly, but not in your first example.

Comment: @Louis Go


test(test&&) might take place when you assign a lvalue to another lvalue ??????????????????? 



 test(test&&) takes an rvalue as a parameter . it does not take an lvalue as a parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So why the constructor `test(test&&c) noexcept` is not called?

This is due to [**non-mandatory copy elison**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) prior to C++17.Under certain circumstances, the compilers are **permitted**, but not required **to omit the copy and move (since C++11) construction of class objects**.

You can verify this by providing the flag `-fno-elide-constructors` in your 2nd example. And you'll get your expected output. [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/injH5cqa8cVyYLoE).

```
class test {
public:
    test(int y) {
        printf(" test(int y)\n");
    }
    test() {
        printf(" test()\n");
    }
    test(test&& c) noexcept {
        printf(" test(test&&c) noexcept\n");
    }
    test(const test& z) {
        printf(" test(const test&z)\n");
    }
    test& operator=(test e) {
        printf(" test& operator=( test e)\n");
        return *this;
    }
};
int main()
{
    test o;
    o = 4;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output** with `-fno-elide-constructors` flag:

```
test()
test(int y)
test(test&&c) noexcept
test& operator=( test e)
```

[Working demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/injH5cqa8cVyYLoE).

---

And if you don't provide this flag, then compilers are allowed to elide the copy/move construction in this situation and hence you were getting the output you mentioned.

---

##### C++17

Note that from C++17 onwards, the flag `-fno-elide-constructors` won't have any effect on the output becasue of the [mandatory copy elison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

Comment: The *important thing* you added is very essential. Would you like to give it a header?

Comment: @LouisGo By header do you mean more explanation or use it as a title. Can you clarify. In case you mean more explanation for that so here it is. Since `e` is a parameter of the assignment `operator=`, so it(`e`) will be destroyed when this assignment call is finished. Thus the reference that you returned becomes a dangling reference. And using that dangling reference will be undefined behavior.

Comment: Please provide a header like `## Dangling reference issue` or other meaningful title of the explanation.

Comment: @LouisGo I have added a title for that so that it(the issue) is more easily visible. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I edited my mistake in the question so you can delete the section you wrote about it and please edit the demo code you wrote else @Anoop Rana

Comment: I will not edit my questions again but can you kindly edit your answer ( the code you took from my question , the demo code and delete the section you wrote )
@Anoop Rana

Comment: @f877576 As per your request i have removed that part.