# Using std::move when returning an object

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, stdmove

If I have the following function:

```
MyObject Process(std::string par1, int par2){
     MyObject message;
     // Do some processing here
    return message;
}
```

Can this be implemented like this:

```
MyObject Process(std::string par1, int par2){
         MyObject message;
         // Do some processing here
        return std::move(message);
    }
```

And what is the difference between both? (I have the notion that the second one will not copy the object `message` but just move it, but since `message` function scope is finishing, what does this represent?

Comment: You don't need to use `std::move` explicitly because of the implicit move rule.

Comment: @AnoopRana Does that mean that there is no difference and it is implicitly moved? I thought that returning it would copy the object to another object

Comment: Refer to the first [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71934476/12002570) that i linked to your question where i have explained what will happen and why. Additionally check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72383114/does-returning-a-local-variable-return-a-copy-and-destroy-the-original/72386932#72386932) which can also be helpful.

Comment: `std::move` can make it worse but never better. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: @KansaiRobot - Moving does not magically teleport objects. All it does is affect overload resolution to determine how the target is initialized. In return statements there may be an implicit move, is all. (Well not quite *all*, a move or (N)RVO  , which makes objects alias under the hood, thus avoiding more than one object.)