# Returning lvalue from function

Tags: c++, lvalue

Why the result of returning lvalue from function is that that object `std::vector<int> v` in `main()` function has same memory address as returned object `std::vector<int> vec` in a `get_vec()` function, even though these objects exist in a different stack frame ?

Why there is not called move constructor ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


std::vector<int> get_vec()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; 
    std::cout << "get_vec():\n" << &vec << '\n' << vec.data() << "\n\n";   
    return vec;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = get_vec();
    std::cout << "main():\n" << &v << '\n' << v.data() << "\n\n";   
  
    return 0;
}
```

```
OUTPUT:
get_vec():
0x7a07ee93baa0
0x226b290

main():
0x7a07ee93baa0
0x226b290
```

Comment: See nrvo explained in [dupe1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72386932/12002570) and implicit move rule explained in [dupe2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71934476/12002570)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vec` is either moved (automatically, because you're [returning a local variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return#Automatic_move_from_local_variables_and_parameters)), or, if the compiler is smart enough, is the same object as `v` (this is called NRVO).

In both cases `.data()` is going to stay the same. When moved, the new vector takes ownership of the other vector's heap memory.

`&vec`,`&v` are going to be the same only if the compiler performs NRVO.

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing `v` with the result of `get_vec` and the return value undergoes [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

Internally the C++ calling convention has a register for returning structs by passing in a pointer to storage. So the call gets transformed into:

```
void get_vec(std::vector<int> &out);
```

The function gets a reference to the `v` in main so the address is the same in both cases.